# newman environment variables - avoid using --env-var after each variable pass

Tags: postman, newman

I want to pass **multiple environment variables** using the `newman CLI`.

```
newman run myCollection.json --env-var baseurl="fancy/url" --env-var user="admin" --env-var password="admin123" `
```

I hate that I have to write `-env-var` for each of the variables I want to set..

Is there a nicer way to do it?

I want to avoid passing the environment variables to newman as `json`.

Answer (score 2):

If(as you said) the usage of environment/Global JSON files is not an option, i would suggest to a data file. You cann add the credentials in an csv file as username,password pairs. E.g.

```
user,password
"admin","admin123"
```

You only have to add `-d "datafile.csv"` to your newman command

You can access them by using `data.user` and `data.password` in your test-code. If you need them in the request-body, URL, or header: Just use {{user}} an {{password}} aus usual.

An other benefit:
With datafiles you can execute each collection for multiple times(aka. iterations), for each row.